# Fluentd - file buffer setup for redis_output (or elasticsearch) with multiprocess workers

Tags: fluentd

Can someone help me how to configure the `file` buffer for multiprocess workers in fluentd?
I use this config, but when I add `@type file+id` to buffer for `redis_store` plugin, it throws this error:

```
failed to configure sub output copy: Plugin 'file' does not support multi workers configuration"
```

without `id` it failed with:

```
failed to configure sub output copy: Other 'redis_store' plugin already use same buffer path
```

But there is a tag in `path` and for different outputs (file) it works, it doesn't work only with Redis output.

I don't want to use the default memory buffer for this because of increasing memory when there is too much data. Is it possible to config this combo? (multiprocess+file buffer for `redis_store` plugin or Elasticsearch plugin?)

Configuration:

```
<system>
  workers 4
  root_dir /fluentd/log/buffer/
</system>

<worker 0-3>
<source>
 @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 9880
</source>

<label @TEST>
<match test.**> 
 @type forest
 subtype copy
 <template>
 <store>
    @type file
    @id "file_${tag_parts[2]}/${tag_parts[3]}/${tag_parts[3]}-#{worker_id}"
    @log_level debug
    path "fluentd/log/${tag_parts[2]}/${tag_parts[3]}/${tag_parts[3]}-#{worker_id}.*.log"
    append true
 <buffer>
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 3
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
 <format>
  @type single_value
  message_key log
 </format>
 </store>
 <store>
     @type redis_store
     host server_ip
     port 6379
     key test
     store_type list
 <buffer>
    #@type file CANT USE
    #id test_${tag_parts[2]}/${tag_parts[3]}/${tag_parts[3]}-#{worker_id}  WITH ID - DOESNT SUPPORT MULTIPROCESS.. 
    #path fluentd/log/${tag_parts[2]}/${tag_parts[3]}/${tag_parts[3]}-#{worker_id}.*.log WITHOUT ID - OTHER PLUGIN USE SAME BUFFER PATH
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 3
    flush_at_shutdown true
    flush_thread_count 4
  </buffer>
 </store>
  </template>
</match>
</label>
</worker>
```

Versions:

- Fluentd v1.14.3
- fluent-plugin-redis-store v0.2.0
- fluent-plugin-forest v0.3.3

Thanks!

Comment: Does this configuration work without the `file` buffer?

Comment: Yes it works without file buffer (with default memory buffer) RIght now there are not so many data (cca 1k/s now) and without redis output the memory is stable but with it the memory is still slowly increasing so I'm trying to figure out how to handle it and file buffer maybe can be the right way I hope..

Comment: Doesn't the memory usage go down with each flush? In the above config, there are two output stores configured: `file` and `redis-store`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Looks like that `redis-store` plugin supports `buffer` and multi-workers? See: https://github.com/pokehanai/fluent-plugin-redis-store/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/out_redis_store.rb#L35-L37 and https://github.com/pokehanai/fluent-plugin-redis-store/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/out_redis_store.rb#L78-L80.

Comment: Please add your fluentd version, plugins, and their versions also. Why are you using `forest`'s `copy` and not the [`copy`](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/copy) plugin directly? Is there any special use-case that you're tackling with an external plugin?

Comment: There are two outputs because I need to save the logs on disc as backup + send them to redis. After each flush maybe memory goes down but I dont see it on my monitoring - it looks like smooth line without peaks (8cpu, 16GB RAM, 1,3 system load). I use forest plugin because it can save the logs to many directories dynamically via tag_parts (cca 30 env dirs and every has cca 40 app dirs) and I didnt find out how to do that with only copy plugin. Do you think that the forest plugin can be the problem here?

Comment: I know that redis_store supports multi-workers - it looks ok with that configuration. I only dont know how to force the redis plugin not to use memory buffer - it really looks like that the memory is stable if the logs are saved to disc, but when I start to send them to redis, the memory starts to increase.

Comment: Versions added and I changed the path to tag_parts (the config was simplified). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis_store config was wrong, correct version has id under FIRST @type:

```
<store>
     @type redis_store
     @id test_${tag_parts[2]}/${tag_parts[3]}/${tag_parts[3]}-#{worker_id} 
     host server_ip
     port 6379
     key test
     store_type list
 <buffer>
    @type file
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 3
    flush_at_shutdown true
    flush_thread_count 4
  </buffer>
 </store>
```

Thank you for your time Azeem :)

Comment: You're welcome! :-)